# DNS issue with virtual host

Tags: apache, dns, xampp, wamp

I get this message

> The server at **reports** can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

and I have the following setup as virtual hosts in my XAMPP folder

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\PeadInstalation\php\Paed\reports"
    ServerName Reports
    <Directory  "C:\PeadInstalation\php\Paed\reports">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and in my **hosts** file I have the following.

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost   
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       Reports   
::1             Reports
```

This setup has worked on 3 separate machines before we tried this one.
This one how-ever gives me the message above.

I have cleared the cache of chrome as-well.

Any ideas please?

PS - Ive added WAMP tag as-well, because Ive tried in with WAMP also.

I am about to try this, but just need permission to restart the server afterwords.

> Click windows button
>
> type cmd --- on the shortcut, right click and Run as Admin
>
> type ipconfig /flushdns press enter
> click windows button --- Control panel
> under Network and Internet click >  View network status and tasks
> upper left click change adapter settings
>
> right click on your connection, Local area connection is if you're wired, > >Wireless Network Connection if wireless --- click Properties
>
> click to highlight Internet Protocol Version 4
> click Properties button
> click Use the following DNS server addresses and in >the
> boxes type 208.67.222.222 as Preferred and 208.67.220.220 as Alternate
>
> click OK, Close and close network connections
>
> reboot your computer and try it.   Those 2 things flushed all DNS entries in >your
> DNS cache and then we changed the default DNS servers to OpenDNS
> servers, some of the best out there. Report back what happens for you.--

Comment: Have you tried making `Reports` all lower case i.e. `reports` In `hosts` file and the `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: Also use the unix `/` rather than the Dos \ in the `DocumentRoot "C:\PeadInstalation\php\Paed\reports"` and ` <Directory  "C:\PeadInstalation\php\Paed\reports">` I am guessing this is just a local typo

Comment: @RiggsFolly, No luck Im afraid. Possible internet group policy that the machine is constraint with perhaps (firewall or antivirus)? The firewall accepts chrome from what I could see locally. and Im trying to open a local file.

Answer (score 0):

Because all this is local to your PC changing DNS server should be irrelevant as you are not using them.

Just on the off chance that this PC has got its network stack panties in a bunch, try this, its not destructive but might reset things

```
Open a command prompt as Administrator

Run

netsh winsock reset
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns

Reboot if necessary

Try apache again
```

Comment: No luck yet, I have to wait for a IT department restart of the server, but for now I assume the fact that google search cant be reached, if because I have run these commands. Am I right?